# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ in androidstudio

Tags: arrays, json, string, gson

Showing this error on running the code in android studio. I don't understand what to do:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible codes with texts instead of pictures here.